# Asynchronous tasks not working if called in OnCreate method

Tags: android, asynchronous, bluetooth, oncreate, android-bluetooth

I'm pretty new to android and I am building my first app.
Up until this point, all of my activities were static and I could implement them in
OnCreate method. However, I ran into a problem when I tried to use startDiscovery(); for bluetooth. The page kept crashing whenever I call startDiscovery() in onCreate method. I thought about it for a moment and reached a conclusion that it is crashing because startDiscovery() is asynchronous and this is stopping the program to create the page because the onCreate method has to be finished for the program to correctly display the page.

I would really appreciate any help regarding:

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. So... how can I implement this? (i.e. use startDiscovery without error)

Edit: Here is stripped version of my code:

```
public class TrashcanOnWayActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trashcan_on_way);


// ==================================== Bluetooth ====================================
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    final TextView bluelist =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.list1);

    // Turn on Bluetooth
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }


    boolean test = false;
    test = mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    if (test == true)
    {
        bluelist.setText("found one" );         
    }
    else
    {
        bluelist.setText("didn't find one" );                   
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();}
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
04-21 15:48:12.496: I/ActivityManager(430): Displayed com.example.trash2/.LocationPaperActivity: +150ms
04-21 15:48:14.126: I/ActivityManager(430): START u0 {cmp=com.example.trash2/.TrashcanOnWayActivity} from pid 10470
04-21 15:48:14.176: D/BluetoothManagerService(430): Message: 20
04-21 15:48:14.176: D/BluetoothManagerService(430): Added callback: android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManagerCallback$Stub$Proxy@4261b200:true
04-21 15:48:14.176: D/AndroidRuntime(10470): Shutting down VM
04-21 15:48:14.176: W/dalvikvm(10470): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41974700)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trash2/com.example.trash2.TrashcanOnWayActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH ADMIN permission: Neither user 10072 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH ADMIN permission: Neither user 10072 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.startDiscovery(IBluetooth.java:790)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(BluetoothAdapter.java:770)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at com.example.trash2.TrashcanOnWayActivity.onCreate(TrashcanOnWayActivity.java:89)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-21 15:48:14.186: E/AndroidRuntime(10470):    ... 11 more
04-21 15:48:14.196: W/ActivityManager(430):   Force finishing activity com.example.trash2/.TrashcanOnWayActivity
04-21 15:48:14.196: W/ActivityManager(430):   Force finishing activity com.example.trash2/.LocationPaperActivity
04-21 15:48:14.286: D/dalvikvm(430): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4373K, 29% free 23450K/33004K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 74ms
04-21 15:48:14.696: W/ActivityManager(430): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{423f0138 u0 com.example.trash2/.TrashcanOnWayActivity}
04-21 15:48:24.146: W/ActivityManager(430): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-21 15:48:24.146: W/ActivityManager(430): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{423f0138 u0 com.example.trash2/.TrashcanOnWayActivity}
04-21 15:48:24.696: W/ActivityManager(430): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{420fd358 u0 com.example.trash2/.MainActivity}
04-21 15:48:34.166: W/ActivityManager(430): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{423b9698 u0 com.example.trash2/.LocationPaperActivity}
04-21 15:48:34.166: W/ActivityManager(430): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{423f0138 u0 com.example.trash2/.TrashcanOnWayActivity}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in the logcat and how does the code look like that produced the crash?

Comment: Have you added into your manifest file the permission for the Bluetooth?

Comment: yes I added the permission

Comment: The logcat is quite explicit: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH ADMIN permission` -- you don't have bluetooth admin permission.

Comment: oh.. i didn't put ADMIN option .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log states that you don't have the permission for bluetooth. Make sure you dind't write it wrong in the manifest. Needs to be as next

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Also make sure you put the permission in the wrong place within the manifest. You "MUST" write it at root level of the manifest, and "NOT" within any other tag.